# How to insert values to excel cells using a Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, excel-2007

Im trying to pass 8 string values in to a row in an already existing excel spreadsheet and then be able to select that row programmatically using C#. I am using a Windows Service with a file system watcher that is constantly monitoring a directory for a file to be added once the file is added it needs to extract the file contents in to object properties and then write them to an excel sheet. Would anyone have any idea how to do this without having to pay for any additional excel extensions? I am using excel 2007 and Visual Studio 2012. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Bernard

Comment: this may help you a little http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/156324/Saving-excel-workbook-in-windows-service-C

Comment: Thanks that was quite helpful. I got it working but cant post the answer for another 5 hours due to my reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I actually got it working there. I used the following code to write to a specific cell in an already existing excel sheet:

```
 string path = @"C:\ProjectTesting\TwsDde.xlsm";

        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        oXL.Visible = true;

        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

        mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        //Get all the sheets in the workbook

        mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;

        //Get the allready exists sheet

        mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Basic Orders");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range= mWSheet1.UsedRange;

        mWSheet1.Cells[12, 1] = "bla bla bla";
```

This code was taken from this article which also goes on to save the excel sheet:

http://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/programmatically-insert-to-existing-excel-file-using-c/

I hope this helps somebody else.

Thanks

Bernard